# want to get proper path for adding file into resource folder java web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to get the real path of resource folder subfolder(resource/json).

i tried below mention ways.

```
  URL resource = Helper.class.getResource("/json");
  String _path = resource.getPath();

 File file = new File(resource.toURI()).getAbsoluteFile();
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 Resource rc = new ClassPathResource("/json");
 String res = rc.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
 -------------------------------------------------------------
 ServletContext context = req.getServletContext();
 String ctx = context.getRealPath("/Test/WEB-INF/classes/json");
```

i am getting eclipse temp directory path only.

```
 "/home/sanjay/test/workspace/testworkspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Test/WEB-INF/classes/json"
```

I want to store file on same folder runtime.